# What is better: Static variable V.S. Asp.NET Application Session?

Tags: asp.net, global-variables, static-members

Say you want to share some resource, like a class or a variable across all threads/sessions within a ASP.NET web application.  What is better?

1) A static variable having thread-safe accessors to that static variable?

2) Or a ASP.NET application session variable?

Comment: This is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303725/asp-net-application-state-vs-a-static-object

Comment: Ahh ok... I didn't see that... what should I do just close this question then?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only have one of those, there is little difference.

If you have several, you should use static variables rather than `Application` variables. The `Application.Lock` method will lock *all* `Application` variables, while you can use separate syncronisition identifiers for your static variables, so that each lock only affects the code that accesses that specific variable.

Comment: So what about if the site is in a web farm? and do you have an example of this.

Comment: @Choco: Then you can't actually share the same object, as you send data between servers. Here's an article that gives an overview of the options: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180726/State-management-and-ways-to-handle-Cache-in-a-Web

Answer (score 4):

Static Members will offer better performance, but the down-side is they are not thread safe:

*It is recommended that you store data in static members of the application class instead of in the Application object. This increases performance because you can access a static variable faster than you can access an item in the Application dictionary.*

From: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q312607

and:

http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2003/12/01/40526.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's true session variables should only be used for if you want to store the value for the whole session, but in the case you want the variables to be intitialized and to be used in between the forms and if changed in betwwen should be available through the whole application for the same object must use static variables.

Answer (score -1):

This is a common scenario in which you are going through multiple pages and collecting data. I would use a Session object for this scenario. Static variables should be used when the complete application is in need for the same object.

If the value you want to hold is dependent on the user then use Session.