# How to handle concurrent connections asp net (c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, session-cookies

I have written a simple webapp in asp net. The first time I go through the program Everything works fine, but if I go there again it uses that variables from my last session.

So the questions are

1. Is there anyway to correct this?
2. Does it have something to do with how I make my public variables?
3. Could I store the variables as cookies, then delete them when the page closes?

This is how I make my public variables:

```
static class vars
{
    public static List<string> directory_names = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> directory = new List<string>();  
    public static int numvar = 0;
    //There are more but they all are made the same way
}
```

Any Ideas are welcome.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid static as it means the variable will be the same for every user connected (plus you will probably face threading issue).

Here is a link on SO about this: [What is better: Static variable V.S. Asp.NET Application Session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894036/what-is-better-static-variable-v-s-asp-net-application-session)

Comment: So from what I am reading, I create the variables using session and then each user who logs on will get their own set of variables?  Please correct me if I am thinking wrong.

Comment: @Adam8797 - yes, session variable are, erh... per session. A session is valid until it times out. Here is an extensive article on ASP.NET sessions: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are several thing we need to address here.

First of all, I think there are more code involved than the class you provided. I think you need to add that in order for us to give you an accurate answer.

However, from what I can see from the class you have provided, there is one thing in particular that you have done and that is the `static` keyword.

The `static` keyword on a class and/or a property means that there is only one instance in the entire [application domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxk374d9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). This means that all requests to you website will share the values of your `vars` class as there is only one instance.

I suggest you to follow some ASP.NET tutorials and videos, to gather some basic understanding in ASP.NET. Get started here, they have excellent material: http://www.asp.net/get-started

Read more on the static keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx(v=VS.100).aspx