# How to dynamically set the maxlength property of bound textbox from database field length

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net 4.0 c# web application. I am using listview and formview controls with templates on my forms. I am trying to control the maxlength property of my bound textboxes without hard coding the field sizes into my aspx pages. I would like to when I first load the application fill some kind of local object or array with the column lengths of my fields and then use those values to dynamically set the maxLength field of textboxes.
There are so many methods out there to try and I am not sure what is the most efficient.
My sql to get the schema info is

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT sys.sysobjects.name AS TableName, sys.syscolumns.name AS ColumnName, sys.systypes.name AS DataType, 
                      sys.syscolumns.length
FROM         sys.sysobjects INNER JOIN
                      sys.syscolumns ON sys.sysobjects.id = sys.syscolumns.id INNER JOIN
                      sys.systypes ON sys.syscolumns.xtype = sys.systypes.xtype WHERE     (sys.sysobjects.xtype = 'U') AND (sys.systypes.name <> 'sysname')
ORDER BY TableName, sys.syscolumns.colid
```

how can i store this locally so I don't have to keep querying the server and I can I set this dynamically using c#

I am a semi newbie so as much detail as can be provided would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See you are getting the column lengths from the database, now you need to do this `txtBox.MaxLength`.
Doing this dynamically can be avoided if you already design your aspx pages tightly coupled with database tables.
But if you are sure you want to go this way then:
1.) On application start up fetch all the values from the DB and make a dictionary cache out of it, it will sit in memory as long as the application is up.
2.) Now, on each page load you need to read those values from the dictionary and use `TextBox.MaxLength` property to set the values. This way you are adjusting the max length property before it is delivered to the client machine.
Thats it !!!

Anyways, any approach of this sort will bring down application performance. Consider pre-designing aspx pages.

Comment: what do you mean by "aspx pages tightly coupled with database tables"? What do you mean by "pre-designing aspx pages"?

Comment: also, how do I make a dictionary cache out of it?

Comment: By tightly coupled i mean: Fix a DB design first and then based on DB fields make aspx pages, coz ultimately your aspx pages are feeding data to your DB tables.

Comment: For making a cache you can look into System.Caching for a start, you can also look into Esent persistent dictionary.

Comment: thanks for your answers. i am trying different options and will get back to you when I figure out what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways of doing this, static variables (essentially global variables) or using the application cache. Personally I prefer static variables as I find the API for `System.Web.Caching` to be over-complicated.

This is how you use static variables with a bit of a discussion on which is the best method (including how to use the new `Lazy` class in .Net 4.0+):

[Why use System.Runtime.Caching or System.Web.Caching Vs static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986466/why-use-system-runtime-caching-or-system-web-caching-vs-static-variables)

This is how to use System.Web.Caching:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx

I wouldn't worry too much about which is more efficient, the methods of doing this are almost identical performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. For my purposes I just kept it simple because this is a relatively small app.
Since I am using templates I have the same field defined multiple times in many places. Since my application data fields will be changing not infrequently, this just gives me one place in the application to change the maxLength property.

in my aspx page:
' MaxLength="<%# TableSchema.SomeField1Length%>" />

I made a class

public static class TableSchema
    {

```
    public static  int SomeField1Length
    {
    get { return 15; }

    }

    public static int SomeField2Length
    {
    get { return 100; }

    }

    public static int SomeField3Length
    {
        get { return 15; }

    }
```

}

It's seems to be working ok. I have to see if this causes a performance hit.