# iis w3wp weird behavior - two roots

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7, appdomain

I have a MVC app which runs under IIS 7.0 under .NET 4.5

Every once and a while something weird happens and all my sessions/requests/logs are mixed-up.
I'm using Log4Net for logging and I can see that I have two roots under the w3svc:
w3svc/1/root-x-somelongnumber and w3svc/1/root-y-somedifferentlongnumber
What does it means? is this means that in some point my app domain get recycled from some reason or it might be something else?

Basically I would expect to see only one root.

I've read several posts and this one among them:
[One ASP.NET app (accidentally) in multiple app domains or frequent app recycing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501528/one-asp-net-app-accidentally-in-multiple-app-domains-or-frequent-app-recycing)
I think he has the same problem as what I'm encountering - but I still didn't understand what can cause this - we don't change any configurations file or anything which can cause an app domain recycle... (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx)

Comment: Did you enable IIS health monitoring to check for the app starting twice in quick succession as described in Edit 3 of the SO question to which you linked?

Comment: Does the modified datetime of the `web.config` ever coincide with a change in the logging like you describe?  If `web.config` changes are not occurring, I would expect `web.config`'s modified datetime to be before logged datetimes of course.

Comment: I didn't enable the health monitoring yet - this is my next step. And the web.config indeed wasn't changed (actually all the application files weren't changed).