# static variable and application object

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Application state vs a Static object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303725/asp-net-application-state-vs-a-static-object)

I am using the static variable to share the data between all the users. But we have also application object, with help of the application , we can also share data between all user.
Can any explain, where can we use static variable and the application object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the Application object\static object approach would fail in a multi server scenario. If your state sharing is more of a read only view of some data things may work, but in a read-write scenario things would fail. In such a scenario you need delegate state storage to another machine altogether (such as state server, sql server, memcache etc).
If you compare static and application object i would strongly suggest you to go with Application object as it has some thread synchronization built into it, which can help avoid inconsistent data retrieval.